# R plotly: Custom hover text not displaying for all points in plot_mapbox

Tags: r, mapbox, plotly, shiny

My problem is that i am trying to add custom hover text to a plotly scattermapbox in R. I have found that I can include the text that I want without specifying hoverinfo = 'text', however this gives me unwanted output (i.e. longitude and latitude, see “Map” example below). When i specify the hoverinfo argument, the desired text does not display for all points. Can anyone help me get the custom hover text without the additional information in the tooltip?

```
library(plotly)

Sys.setenv('MAPBOX_TOKEN' = 'mapbox_token' )

Test <- data.frame(
Postcode = c(801, 820, 820, 822, 822),
Name_Organisation = c("Google", "Apple", "Microsoft","IBM","Rstudio"),
Org_Type = c("Training Provider","National Laboratory & Testing Facility","National Laboratory & Testing Facility","National Laboratory & Testing Facility", "Training Provider"),
State = c("NT","NT","NT","NT","NT"),
Latitude = c(-12.80081,-12.41066,-12.40957,-12.79939,-12.89939),
Longitude = c(130.9598,130.8604,130.8598,131.1294,131.1294),
RDOrgCap = c("Training Centres & Facilities","Testing facilities (public & private)","Testing facilities (public & private)","Testing facilities (public & private)","Testing facilities (public & private)")
)

basic <- list(method = "relayout",
              args = list(list(mapbox.style = "basic")),
              label = "Basic")

dark <- list(method = "relayout",
             args = list(list(mapbox.style = "dark")),
             label = "Dark")

satellite <- list(method = "relayout",
                  args = list(list(mapbox.style = "satellite")),
                  label = "Satellite")  

#Hovertext works
Map <- plot_mapbox(data = Test, lon=~Longitude, lat = ~Latitude, type = "scattermapbox", mode = "markers",split = ~RDOrgCap,text = ~paste("State: ",State,"<br>","Region (Postcode): ",Postcode,"<br>", "Organisation Name: ",Name_Organisation, "<br>", "Organisation Type: ",Org_Type,sep = "" )) %>%
  layout(mapbox = list(zoom = 3.5,
                       center = list(lat =-27 ,
                                     lon =133)),  legend = list(opacity= 1)
  ) %>%
  layout(updatemenus = list(list(x = -0.01,
                                 y = 1,buttons= list(basic,dark,satellite))))


Map

#Hovertext does not work
Map_1 <- plot_mapbox(data = Test, lon=~Longitude, lat = ~Latitude, type = "scattermapbox", mode = "markers", hoverinfo = 'text',split = ~RDOrgCap,text = ~paste("State: ",State,"<br>","Region (Postcode): ",Postcode,"<br>", "Organisation Name: ",Name_Organisation, "<br>", "Organisation Type: ",Org_Type,sep = "" )) %>%
  layout(mapbox = list(zoom = 3.5,
                       center = list(lat =-27 ,
                                     lon =133)),  legend = list(opacity= 1)
  ) %>%
  layout(updatemenus = list(list(x = -0.01,
                                 y = 1,buttons= list(basic,dark,satellite))))


Map_1
```

Note that I previously was able to do this without any issues about 3 months ago, however I have since then updated both R and plotly. unfortunately I do not know what version I was previously using, however I am currently using R version 3.4.1 and plotly version 4.7.1

Comment: If you updated R and then reinstalled all the packages, getting an updated plotly version, your older library directory may still be available in your computer with your older plotly version. Have you checked the paths in .libPaths()?